# R accessing data by $ in list

Tags: r, subset

I understand I'm probably lacking some basic knowledge.
However, could someone please clarify why the same structure works in one code but not in the other?

Data:

```
> head(Countries)
   LocID NamePrint TreeLevel TypeNameShort IsSmallCountry ParentID
15   1   A         4         Country              0       10
16   2   B         4         Country              0       10
17   3   C         4         Country              0       10
18   4   D         4         Country              0       10
19   5   E         4         Country              0       10
20   6   F         4         Country              0       10
```

Sequence:

```
CountryIdx <- 1
Location <- Countries[CountryIdx,,drop=F]
ParentLocation <- subset(Locations, LocID==Location$ParentID)
GrandParentLocation <- subset(Locations, LocID==ParentLocation$ParentID)

> typeof(Location)
[1] "list"

> typeof(ParentLocation)
[1] "list"

> typeof(GrandParentLocation)
[1] "list"

> class(Location)
[1] "data.frame"

> class(ParentLocation)
[1] "data.frame"

> Location
   LocID NamePrint TreeLevel TypeNameShort IsSmallCountry ParentID
15   1   A         4         Country             0        10

> ParentLocation
   LocID NamePrint TreeLevel TypeNameShort IsSmallCountry ParentID
14   10  XF        3         Unknown             0        30
```

Now the problem:

```
PropUrbanRuralCountry <- subset(PropUrbanRural, LocID==Location$LocID)
```

The line abovefails: `Error in Location$LocID : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

```
> PropUrbanRuralCountry <- subset(PropUrbanRural, LocID==ParentLocation$LocID)
```

The line above works

If Location and ParentLocation are both lists, and subset is using the same data, why one fails and the other doesn't?

Ideally, I'd like to always use the $, but I can't figure out why the same type of data (list). I wish R could simplify his.

Comment: Why not make the example fully reproducible by including the output of `dput(head(Countries))`?

Comment: Are you sure there's not a column named Location in `PropUrbanRural` (you haven't shown any details about that table)? Also you should probably use `class()` rather than `typeof()` to really know what an object **is**.

Comment: @MrFlick I think you found the issue! Thank you!

Comment: @igorjrr: If you can post your answer to help future readers, that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @MrFlick in the comments, the `PropUrbanRural` dataset had a column named `Location` that caused R to refer to that column instead of the separate `Location` dataset. I renamed the column and now it works. Thank you, @MrFlick.

Comment: That's why I prefer not using `subset` function but the more common `DF[DF$foo == bar,]` method